# Different results bettween coalb and local machine

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained multi output model in colab the model branch one will classify an image using passion loss the other branch will segment using binary crossentropy loss and using dicecoef as accuracy , when trained on colab the model gives good result accuracy:99,dicecoef:90

however when trained on my local machine one of two usually accurcuy  goes to zero after first epoch, nothing has changed used same code , same data only difference is I used tensorflow 2.5 while on colab it was 2.6.

I appoliges for the dirty codeing.

```
   import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' # or any {'0', '1', '2'}

import tensorflow as tf

import random

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tqdm import tqdm

from skimage.io import imread , imshow

from skimage.transform import resize

# example of pixel normalization

from numpy import asarray

# load image

import shutil

#import cv2 as cv


import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

from tensorflow.keras.losses import binary_crossentropy


beta = 0.25

alpha = 0.25

gamma = 2

epsilon = 1e-5

smooth = 1



class Semantic_loss_functions(object):

def __init__(self):

print ("semantic loss functions initialized")


def dice_coef(self, y_true, y_pred):

y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)

y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)

intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)

return (2. * intersection + K.epsilon()) / (

K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + K.epsilon())


def sensitivity(self, y_true, y_pred):

true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))

possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))

return true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())


def specificity(self, y_true, y_pred):

true_negatives = K.sum(

K.round(K.clip((1 - y_true) * (1 - y_pred), 0, 1)))

possible_negatives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(1 - y_true, 0, 1)))

return true_negatives / (possible_negatives + K.epsilon())


def convert_to_logits(self, y_pred):

y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, tf.keras.backend.epsilon(),

1 - tf.keras.backend.epsilon())

return tf.math.log(y_pred / (1 - y_pred))


def weighted_cross_entropyloss(self, y_true, y_pred):

y_pred = self.convert_to_logits(y_pred)

pos_weight = beta / (1 - beta)

loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred,

targets=y_true,

pos_weight=pos_weight)

return tf.reduce_mean(loss)


def focal_loss_with_logits(self, logits, targets, alpha, gamma, y_pred):

weight_a = alpha * (1 - y_pred) ** gamma * targets

weight_b = (1 - alpha) * y_pred ** gamma * (1 - targets)


return (tf.math.log1p(tf.exp(-tf.abs(logits))) + tf.nn.relu(

-logits)) * (weight_a + weight_b) + logits * weight_b


def focal_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):

y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, tf.keras.backend.epsilon(),

1 - tf.keras.backend.epsilon())

logits = tf.math.log(y_pred / (1 - y_pred))


loss = self.focal_loss_with_logits(logits=logits, targets=y_true,

alpha=alpha, gamma=gamma, y_pred=y_pred)


return tf.reduce_mean(loss)


def depth_softmax(self, matrix):

sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + K.exp(-x))

sigmoided_matrix = sigmoid(matrix)

softmax_matrix = sigmoided_matrix / K.sum(sigmoided_matrix, axis=0)

return softmax_matrix


def generalized_dice_coefficient(self, y_true, y_pred):

smooth = 1.

y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)

y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)

intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)

score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (

K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

return score


def dice_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):

loss = 1 - self.generalized_dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred)

return loss


def bce_dice_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):

loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) + \

self.dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)

return loss / 2.0


def confusion(self, y_true, y_pred):

smooth = 1

y_pred_pos = K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)

y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos

y_pos = K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)

y_neg = 1 - y_pos

tp = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos)

fp = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_pos)

fn = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_neg)

prec = (tp + smooth) / (tp + fp + smooth)

recall = (tp + smooth) / (tp + fn + smooth)

return prec, recall


def true_positive(self, y_true, y_pred):

smooth = 1

y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))

y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))

tp = (K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos) + smooth) / (K.sum(y_pos) + smooth)

return tp


def true_negative(self, y_true, y_pred):

smooth = 1

y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))

y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos

y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))

y_neg = 1 - y_pos

tn = (K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg) + smooth) / (K.sum(y_neg) + smooth)

return tn


def tversky_index(self, y_true, y_pred):

y_true_pos = K.flatten(y_true)

y_pred_pos = K.flatten(y_pred)

true_pos = K.sum(y_true_pos * y_pred_pos)

false_neg = K.sum(y_true_pos * (1 - y_pred_pos))

false_pos = K.sum((1 - y_true_pos) * y_pred_pos)

alpha = 0.7

return (true_pos + smooth) / (true_pos + alpha * false_neg + (

1 - alpha) * false_pos + smooth)


def tversky_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):

return 1 - self.tversky_index(y_true, y_pred)


def focal_tversky(self, y_true, y_pred):

pt_1 = self.tversky_index(y_true, y_pred)

gamma = 0.75

return K.pow((1 - pt_1), gamma)


def log_cosh_dice_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):

x = self.dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)

return tf.math.log((tf.exp(x) + tf.exp(-x)) / 2.0)

########

n_filters=50

epochs=50

batch_size=6

Img_wedth =128

Img_height = 128

Img_channels = 1




#####################################

import h5py

paths=os.listdir('C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/imageData/')

## save images in arrays ##

X_train = np.zeros((len(paths) , Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels) , dtype = np.float32)

y_train = np.zeros((len(paths) , Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels ) , dtype = np.float32)

y_train_label=[]

#####################################


for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(paths) , total = len(paths)) :

ttt=[0,0,0]

path = 'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/imageData/'+id_

#print('path.. ',path)

#print('id.. ',id_)

#img = imread(path + '/image/' +id_ + '.png') [: , : ]

img1=h5py.File(path,'r')

# print('path.. ',path)

img=img1['cjdata']['image']

img = resize(img , (Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels) , mode = 'constant' , preserve_range=True)

#print(img.shape)

# imshow(img,cmap="gray")

# plt.show()


img = asarray(img)

img = img.astype('float32')

# normalize to the range 0-1

img = tf.image.per_image_standardization(img)

# print(img[55][55])

#print(img.shape)

X_train[n] = img

# print('path.. ',path)

mask=img1['cjdata']['tumorMask']

mask = asarray(mask)

mask = mask.astype('float32')

#_,mask=cv.threshold(mask, 0.01, 1, 0 )

mask = resize(mask , (Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels) , mode = 'constant' , preserve_range=True)

#print(img.shape)

# imshow(img,cmap="gray")

# plt.show()

# normalize to the range 0-1

ttt[int(img1['cjdata']['label'][0][0])-1]=img1['cjdata']['label'][0][0]

y_train_label.append(ttt)

y_train[n] = mask

# print(Mask_[55][55])

# Mask_ = np.expand_dims(resize(Mask_ , (Img_height , Img_wedth) , mode = 'constant' ,

# preserve_range = True) , axis = -1)

# Mask = np.maximum(Mask , Mask_ )


# Mask = np.zeros((Img_height , Img_wedth , 1) , dtype = np.bool)



y_train_label=np.array(y_train_label)

paths_test=os.listdir('C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/test')[10:20]


X_test = np.zeros((len(paths_test) , Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels ) , dtype = np.float32)

y_test = np.zeros((len(paths_test) , Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels ) , dtype = np.float32)

y_test_label= []

print('resizing test images')

for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(paths_test) , total = len(paths_test)) :

path = 'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/test/'+id_

ttt1=[0,0,0]

img1=h5py.File(path,'r')

# print('path.. ',path)

img=img1['cjdata']['image']

img = resize(img , (Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels) , mode = 'constant' , preserve_range=True)

#print(img.shape)

# imshow(img,cmap="gray")

# plt.show()

img = asarray(img)

img = img.astype('float32')

img = tf.image.per_image_standardization(img)


# normalize to the range 0-1

X_test[n]=img

mask=h5py.File(path,'r')

# print('path.. ',path)

mask1=mask['cjdata']['tumorMask']

mask1 = asarray(mask1)

mask1 = mask1.astype('float32')

# _,mask1=cv.threshold(mask1, 0.01, 1, 0 )


mask1 = resize(mask1 , (Img_height , Img_wedth , Img_channels) , mode = 'constant' , preserve_range=True)

#print(img.shape)

# imshow(img,cmap="gray")

# plt.show()

# normalize to the range 0-1

ttt1[int(img1['cjdata']['label'][0][0])-1]=img1['cjdata']['label'][0][0]

y_test_label.append(ttt1)


y_test[n]=mask1

#print('imagetestid..',n,'imagetestname',id_)

#imshow(img)

#plt.show()




#image_x = random.randint(0 , len(Train_ids))

#imshow(X_train[image_x])

#plt.show()

#imshow(np.squeeze( y_train[image_x]))

#plt.show()


## U-net Moudel

inputs = tf.keras.Input((Img_wedth , Img_height , Img_channels ))



c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*1 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(inputs)

c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1 )(c1)

p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2 ))(c1)

print ('Done_c1')


c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*2 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(p1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1 )(c2)


p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2 ))(c2)

print ('Done_c2')


c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*4 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(p2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2 )(c3)


p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2 ))(c3)

print ('Done_c3')


c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*8 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(p3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2 )(c4)


p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=((2,2 )))(c4)

print ('Done_c4')


c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*16 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(p4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3 )(c5)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*16, (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(c5)

print ('Done_c5')

F1=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(c5)

D1=tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu')(F1)

D2=tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax',name='clas')(D1)


u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*8 , (2,2) , strides=(2,2) , padding='same')(c5)

print ('Done_c61')

u6 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([u6 , c4])

print ('Done_c62')

c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*8 ,(3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(u6)

print ('Done_c63')

c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2 )(c6)

c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*8, (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(c6)

print ('Done_c6')


u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*4 , (2,2) , strides=(2,2) , padding='same')(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([u7 , c3])

c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*4 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(u7)

c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2 )(c7)

c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*4 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(c7)

print ('Done_c7')


u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*2 , (2,2) , strides=(2,2) , padding='same')(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([u8 , c2])

c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*2 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(u8)

c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c8)

c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*2 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(c8)

print ('Done_c8')


u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters*1 , (2,2) , strides=(2,2) , padding='same')(c8)

print ('Done_c91')

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([u9 , c1])

print ('Done_c92')

c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*1 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(u9)

print ('Done_c93')

c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(c9)

print ('Done_c94')

c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters*1 , (3,3) , activation='relu'

, kernel_initializer='he_normal' , padding='same')(c9)

print ('Done_c9')


outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1 , (1,1) , activation='sigmoid',name='seg')(c9)

print ('Done_out')

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs] , outputs=[outputs,D2])

print ('Done_model1')







def dice_coef1(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):

print(y_true.shape,y_pred.shape)

intersection = K.sum((y_true )*( tf.round(y_pred)), axis=[1,2,3])

union = K.sum((y_true), axis=[1,2,3]) + K.sum((tf.round(y_pred)), axis=[1,2,3])

dice = K.mean((2. * intersection + smooth)/(union + smooth), axis=0)

return dice





loss={"seg":binary_crossentropy,

"clas":tf.keras.losses.poisson}

metricss={'seg':dice_coef1,

'clas':'Accuracy'}

opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=1,clipnorm=1,lr=0.0001)

s = Semantic_loss_functions()

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics=metricss)

model.summary()


#############

# modelchecpoints


from tensorflow.keras import callbacks




results = model.fit(X_train , [y_train,y_train_label] ,shuffle=True, batch_size =batch_size, epochs=epochs )
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the same exact code produces two different outputs is one of two reasons:

1. **The random seed is different**, so if you haven't tried already you should set it to a constant value (for every library)
2. **Different library versions**, so in this case you should probably look if any of the functions you are using has different behaviour or different default values for distinct versions of the same package.